# Test for only for me

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

If my Name is `Bence` on the server, how can i check only for me?

example: `/testfor`Bence`[x=82,y=64,z=271,r=2]`

I have this error: `The entered UUID is invalid Format.`

Answer (score 1):

Selector arguments can only be used with selectors (`@p`, `@e`, `@a`, `@r`).

You should use a selector, then use the `name=` selector argument to target only people with the name "Bence":

```
/testfor @a[name=Bence,x=82,y=64,z=271,r=2]
```